# Vibrating Bluetooth Bracelet/Watch

Tags: bluetooth, hardware-recommendation, notifications

I'm looking for a device in the form of a bracelet/watch that vibrates when I receive calls and text messages; any recommendations?

Comment: If jawbone UP were more reliable, I'd say ask them to make such a device, but it's not. I don't think Apple's notification center is up for the fast - so you'd be in a jailbreak situation to hack the notification stream even once you have a device that would be willing to receive the "vibrate now" command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into the [Pebble watch](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/597507018/pebble-e-paper-watch-for-iphone-and-android?ref=live)? The company already ships an android/blackberry model and the iPhone version is getting prodigious funding but isn't expected to ship until September 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Vybe does this. It's not very nice looking. http://wearvybe.com